# create an array in jquery of all section ids

Tags: jquery

I have a site that I am building that involves quite a bit of animation. I need to create an array of all the section id in the page. I really have no idea how to do this but a pretty sure this is the right direction. I am first just trying to get those values:

```
 var $find = $('body').find('section[id]');
```

I have tried alerting the output and I just get object Object? Can someone poijt me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by section id

Answer (score 1):

To create `array` of `ids` you can use jQuery [**map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rzVe3/2/)**

```
ids = $('body').find('section').map(function() {
    return this.id;
})

$.each(ids, function(idx, el) {
    alert(el);
})​
```

Comment: This will not create an array of ids.  And it will also match section elements on the page that do not have ids.

Comment: Better although the resulting array will contain empty entries for any section elements that do not have an id value.  Close enough for government work though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code

```
var IDs = [];
$('body').find("section").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
```

It will put all the sections ids to the IDs array.

Answer (score 1):

This will create an array of all the ids.

```
var arr = $.map($("section[id]"), function(o, i){
    return o.id;
});
```

Comment: what is the i argument for in the function?

Comment: The map function has a couple of optional parameters.  The first is the current object in the iteration.  The second is the index of that object.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Answer (score 1):

You question contains the answer itself. The `var $find` is already an object that contains ids for all sections. See following code:

```
​$sections = ​$("body").find("section");
$sections.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Chec [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/RcVa5/1/) fiddle for more info.
​